# spring - how to autowire data source?

Tags: java, spring, datasource, dao, autowired

I'm having some problem with autowire and DI in general, so I hope that someone can help cause I've been stuck for days now.

This is the code:

```
@Service
public class TicketsController implements Controller {
  private TicketManager ticketManager;

  @Autowired
public void setTicketManager(TicketManager ticketManager) {
    this.ticketManager = ticketManager;
}
...
}


@Service
public class SimpleTicketManager implements TicketManager {
  private TicketsDao ticketsDao;

@Autowired
public void setTicketsDao(TicketsDao ticketsDao) {
    this.ticketsDao = ticketsDao;
}
 ...
}

@Repository
public class JdbcTicketDao implements TicketsDao  {
  private DataSource dataSource;
  @Autowired
  public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource)  {
    this.dataSource=dataSource;
      this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);   
     }
...
}

public final class AppContext {
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
BeanFactory factory = context;
TicketsController ticketsController = (TicketsController) factory.getBean("ticketsController");
}
...
}
```

In my beans.xml I've got:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytckdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.mvc" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.svc" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.view" />
```

This doesn't work and I get:

```
Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTicketDao': Injection of autowired dependencies failed
... nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
    No matching bean of type [javax.sql.DataSource] found for dependency.`
```

Can someone please help out with this?  What am I doing wrong? It seems that autowiring is working all until the next step where it fails when injecting dataSource.

**EDIT**: I was playing with the code, and forgot @Autowire before setDataSource() but it is supposed to be there.

Comment: Error message seems to indicate you're trying to `@Autowire` but code shown indicate otherwise. Can you clarify that?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add @Autowired before setDataSource, but it was there and I had the same problem.

Comment: My wild guess is that `beans.xml` is not seen by spring as the applicationContext. If you can provide more details on how you "boot" spring

Comment: Well, I first tried all of this with context listener and appconfig.xml and it didn't work.  And I thought that it was just enough to use getBean() and the code in AppContext. Is it not??

Comment: Sorry, but "show us the code".

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're missing wiring configuration, try

`<context:annotation-config/>`

Answer (score 1):

This will be due to the order of bean instance creation. Your DAO has been instantiated before the dataSource instance created.

Keep your data Source bean definition before

other way is , define your dataSource definitions in a separate xml and import that before

Answer (score 0):

Try `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        p:url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/mytckdb?autoReconnect=true"
        p:username="user" p:password="pass" />
```

I use JPA so generally prefer to create EntityManagerFactory and use that

```
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PU" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean id="jpaAdapter"
                    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="database" value="${database}" />
                    <property name="showSql" value="true" />
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" />
```

Comment: I get the same error. I already tried this dataSource bean cause I found it while searching for solution to this problem. I just can't make this work :(

Comment: btw, I just checked you didn't place @Autowired over _private DataSource dataSource;_. Any reasons?

Comment: You can also try defining bean for _JdbcTicketDao_ in your beans.xml

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using `Spring 2.0` but i think `context:component-scan` was introduced in `Spring 2.5`.
Maybe update spring xml-config and spring dependencies to `2.5`?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytckdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>
```

to

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytckdb"/>
    <property name="username" value="user"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>
```

The property is called `driverClassName`, not `driverClass`.

Also, you don't need multiple `context:component-scan` elements You can change

```
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.mvc" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.svc" />
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.view" />
```

To

```
<context:component-scan base-package="bp.dao,bp.mvc,bp.svc,bp.view" />
```