# My autowired DataSource is returning null in Spring, how come?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, datasource, autowired

I'm trying to set my dataSource to get a connection but it is returning null on conn=dataSource.getConnection();. Here is the relevant code from my DAO:

```
@Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
@Override
    public Acronym findByAcronymId(int acronymId) {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM acronym_table WHERE acronymId = ?";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
```

Here is the database bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id = "dataSource"
    class = "org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_name?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Here's the acronym bean:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id = "acronymDAO" class ="com.user.dao.JdbcAcronymDAO">
        <property name = "dataSource" ref ="dataSource"/>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

Comment: How do you think Spring will wire the DataSource into your class? You need to wire the bean and then Spring will inject the dependency.

Comment: How do I wire the bean to inject the dependency? I'm really new to this

Comment: Take a look at this: https://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/

Comment: @DessertsAndStuff do you have any other configuration files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [spring - how to autowire data source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12786754/spring-how-to-autowire-data-source)

Comment: @ledniov, I added another config file to the question

Comment: @DessertsAndStuff where do you include those `xml` files? are you using `web.xml`?

Comment: I'm not using web xml (that i'm aware of, I haven't modified anything in it if it's default), I'm connecting to a mysql database.

Comment: @DessertsAndStuff in order to help you we need all the configuration details, are you injecting it into dao? is your package scanned for components?

Comment: @ledniov, I have the DataSource only in my DAO and want it to not be null when I run. I don't have any other config files, just the one for my database and for the DAO

Comment: @DessertsAndStuff are you accessing it from controller? what version of spring you are using? maybe you can upload your project somewhere on github or other hosting?

Answer (score 3):

Try to move your `@Autowired` annotation on the field itself, something like this:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Or to put it on constructor level, instead of putting it on setter level.

I believe that the data source bean is not being auto-wired because you're using it on setter level which never gets called.

Comment: Thanks, now I get this error though
`Field dataSource in com.user.dao.JdbcAcronymDAO required a bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' that could not be found.
 - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.datasource.jndi-name) did not find property 'jndi-name'
 - Bean method 'dataSource' not loaded because @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' `

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your spring context xml

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

So that it can scan your classes for the @Autowired annotation

Comment: Thanks I added that which I needed, but the dataSource is still null

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had an extra bean. Once I deleted the acronym bean and setup @Autowired it worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add this here as this question comes so far up the google search results!
This link was invaluable for helping me solve this:

https://www.moreofless.co.uk/spring-mvc-java-autowired-component-null-repository-service/

To summarise, something somewhere is probably instantiating with a new().  If a service is using an autowired property, the service must be autowired as well.

```
@Controller
public class Controller {  

  // !!!!!! This won't work!
  // !!!!!! Autowire the service!
  @GetMapping("/brokenexample")
  public String brokenExample() {
    MyService my = new MyService();
    my.doStuff();
  } 

  @Autowired
  MyService service;   
  
  @GetMapping("/example")
  public String example() {
    service.doStuff();
  }
} 

@Service
public class MyService() {   

  @Autowired
  MyRepository repo;   
  
  public void doStuff() {
    repo.findByName( "foo" );
  }
} 

@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends SomeRepository<My, Long> {   

  List<My> findByName( String name );
}
```