# Spring Boot: Datasource Autowiring Null

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am migrating existing spring based application to spring boot. I am trying to configure data source in the below format.

1) Application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=
databaseName=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
```

2) @Configuration bean with below code

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfig {

  @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
  private String driverClassName;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
  private String url;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
  private String userName;

  @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
  private String password;

  @Primary
  @Bean(name ="OneDataSource")
  public DataSource getDataSource() {

    HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
    config.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    config.setJdbcUrl(url);
    config.setUsername(userName);
    config.setPassword(password);
    HikariDataSource hds=new HikariDataSource(config);
    return hds;
  }
}
```

And trying to use this datasource in one of the classes using the below code

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("OneDataSource")
private DataSource dataSource ;
```

below is the code used in method (this is the existing code used in Spring 1 application)
    this.connect = dataSource.getConnection();

My datasource is null and I am getting the below error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.myApp.integration.service.impl.ServiceControl.initializeConnection(ServiceControl.java:152) ~[main/:?]
    at org.myApp.integration.service.impl.ServiceControl.pingBARDS(ServiceControl.java:193) [main/:?]
    at org.myApp.ws.beImpl.ping(beImpl.java:393) [main/:?]
    at org.myApp.rs.control.beResource.ping(beResource.java:442) [main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]

[2m2020-02-18 11:40:13.337[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m65728[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-9090-exec-1][0;39m [36mo.t.b.w.beImpl         [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Unexpected Error

org.myApp.exception.beException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.myApp.integration.service.impl.ServiceControl.initializeConnection(ServiceControl.java:152)
    at org.myApp.integration.service.impl.ServiceControl.pingBARDS(ServiceControl.java:193)
    at org.myApp.ws.beImpl.ping(beImpl.java:393)
    at org.myApp.rs.control.beResource.ping(beResource.java:442)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHan
    at org.myApp.integration.service.impl.ServiceControl.pingBARDS(ServiceControl.java:201) ~[main/:?]
    at org.myApp.ws.beImpl.ping(beImpl.java:393) [main/:?]
    at org.myApp.rs.control.beResource.ping(beResource.java:442) [main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:189) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:800) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882) [spring-webmvc-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:668) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1417) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_192]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.14.jar:9.0.14]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_192]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.myApp.integration.service.impl.ServiceControl.initializeConnection(ServiceControl.java:152) ~[main/:?]
    at org.myApp.integration.service.impl.ServiceControl.pingBARDS(ServiceControl.java:193) ~[main/:?]
    ... 57 more
```

Can somebody help me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the class where you try to use the resource annotated `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Repository`, etc? Remember, Spring can only populated `@Autowired` resources if it is the one creating the instance.

Comment: yes. it is annotated as @Service

Comment: Don't define your own bean at all; Spring Boot does this for you. Use constructor injection instead of field injection; this will usually demonstrate when you have injection problems.

Comment: Do you have the starter `spring-boot-starter-jdbc` as dependency?

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- let me try constructor injection.

Comment: @SHoko i have this dependency compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:${springBootVersion}")

Comment: Could you share your project structure? Is the main class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` in the root package? Are you sure if your `@Bean` it is initialized in your `@Configuration` class?

Comment: yes..main class is annotated with "@SpringBootApplication". I am able to start and debug it. also I have used "@Configuration" annotation along with "@Bean" annotation. I tried debugging and datasource is getting generated in the datasource bean. But the issue is when I try to use the autowired bean. I am doing something wrong there. @SHoko

Comment: @SHoko soory..was unable to tag you in previous comment

Comment: Both classes (@Configuration and @Service) import the same `Datasource` interface?

Comment: yes. But i think there is a bigger problem to my application. I tried creating a bean using the "@Autowired" annotation in my "@Service" annotated class. The application started fine, but when I try to hit a method in the bean, it threw null pointer. So probably the problem is my spring boot application is not creating instances of beans using @Autowired (Not just datasource bean)

Comment: @SHoko..comment as above

Comment: Thankyou for your help. the bean calling datasource was manually created using new () hence my datasource was null (As spring was not managing this one)

Comment: This could be marked as a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/44807608/4440629
See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70925930/4440629